# How to connect 2 traces with an arc in Altium?

Tags: altium, arc

Assuming I have 2 traces that are at an angle (Not 45 or 90, but some random number) I want to create a bend that connects them. Using interactive routing I can get this:
[image]

[image]

However, it consists of an arc and a straight line. I really don't want the second sharp bend:
So far the closest I have gotten is by placing edge arc and then messing around with radius and angles until it somewhat fits and then clipping it:
[image]

I have asked Altium support, however, they did not know. I think there certainly must be an easy way to connect these 2 lines in a simple manner using an arc. Please let me know what the right technique is.

Comment: Placing arc(edge) is the easiest way. You can place the second point of the edge far away,    then decrease the arc length till the edge meets the second line. By that way you get a very smooth arc joining the two lines

Comment: No direct way of doing it other than with an edge arc as mentioned already, then pull back the angle to get a join to the arbitrary angled line...

Comment: Looking at the properties of the second line, you could calculate its angle from the end points. Then at least you'd know exactly what angles to use in your arc to get a smooth connection.

Comment: But if you're working below 5 Gbps / 2.5 GHz, arcs are pretty much cosmetic and don't provide significant performance benefits.

Comment: @ThePhoton The only other use case for arcs would be in flat flex cables (and can help with strain relief within the cable if it bends)

Comment: Connect the arc to your tracks ... make sure the ends are 'pinned' so they stay connected. 
   Then change the RADIUS until you get the smooth curve you're seeking.   Don't adjust the numbers in the properties box....click and drag the small square in the middle of the arc.   Piece of cake.   :)